# Acidental chmod -R 600 .*

Tags: debian

OMG! I accidentaly executed the command " chmod -R 600 .* "

How do I fix that!?

I'm logged in as root, if I run chmod:
/bin/chmod: Permission denied

If i run ls, mv, or cp:
/bin/ls: Permission denied

If i try to log as root in another ssh window:
I can't

Please, HELP!

Comment: Restore from backups, and be more careful next time.

Comment: well at least now you can't do an rm -f anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your mocking comments

Fortunately, I was able to boot on OVH's Recue Mode, mount the partition, change the files permissions back again and then boot up normally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to boot from a system rescue disk to fix this. More than likely you will need to reinstall everything though to get your system back to a usable and secure state.

This is a good choice for rescue cds:
http://www.sysresccd.org/

Comment: You'll find it easier to reinstall then attempting to fix the damage piecemeal

Answer (score 0):

sudo /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /bin/chmod 755 /bin/chmod

What directory were you in when you did the bad chmod?

If using EL like redhat centos SL you can do `rpm --setperms $(rpm -qa)`

Comment: I was on /tmp, and i can't run sudo either

Comment: youre fine if you were in temp.. it would have only affected /tmp and below.. Try su

Comment: What does the command whoami show?

Comment: Of course `.*` includes `..`, so if you're in `/tmp` then that will include `/`, and hence the problem of not being able to execute *any* file on a file system that was mounted at the time.

Comment: Unfortunately, he's not fine even though he was in /tmp -- his command was "chmod -R 600 .*", which includes "/tmp/.." (which is  the same as "/")

Comment: I host at OVH, they have a netboot with rescue mode there. Is it anything i can do?

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the dot, I was reading it as chmod -R *